# XtraGrid row index mismatch after deleteing a row

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I am currently using a XtraGrid.
I have bound the gridControl to a DataTable. When I delete a row from the DataTable, the XtraGrid shows the change. But when I start dealing with row indexes, I get odd behavior.

This is (roughly) the code I use to delete the row.

```
DataTable dtWorkItems;
...
gridWorkItemList.DataSource = dtWorkItems;
...
int currRowHandle = gridViewWorkItemList.FocusedRowHandle;
int currRowIndex = gridViewWorkItemList.GetDataSourceRowIndex(currRowHandle);
DataRow theRow = gridViewWorkItemList.GetDataRow(currRowHandle);
theRow.Delete();
```

But this test fails afterwards:

```
int rowHandle = gridViewWorkItemList.FocusedRowHandle;
int rowIndex = gridViewWorkItemList.GetDataSourceRowIndex(rowHandle);
DataRow dr1 = gridViewWorkItemList.GetDataRow(rowHandle);
DataRow dr2 = dtWorkItems.Rows[rowIndex];
if (dr1 != dr2)
   ; // Failure
```

In fact, dr2 has a state of "Deleted".

If I do an AcceptChanges() on the dtWorkItems, then the test will pass. But I would rather not do that.

Is there something I have to do to get the row indexes to start matching up again?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete it from the datasource ( dtWorkItems ), then have the grid refresh if it doesn't automatically.  The grid is just a view of the dtWorkItems.  Maybe your already doing that as Acceptchanges works, why don't you want to Accept the changes you made ?

Comment: I don't want to AcceptChanges() because I want to call GetChanges() later.

Comment: Calling `gridViewWorkItemList.RefreshData()` does not get the row indexes back into sync.